# Passing in this.value to methods

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why what I'm doing wrong when passing in `this.value` as a method argument. All field values have type of string and the constructor arguments all of type of string. But when I try to pass in `this.classField` it breaks this:with some weird error about Argument of type this:any is not assignable to type string. What am I not understanding here?

this code works:

```
var sourceApp = this.sourceApp;
var eventType = this.eventType;
var alertType = this.alertType;
var channelType = this.channelType;
var t = new Template({sourceApp, eventType, alertType, channelType});
```

but this code does not:

```
var t = new Template({this.sourceApp, this.eventType, this.alertType, this.channelType});
```

Comment: Nothing to do with TypeScript, that's just how object shorthand works. You want `new Template({ sourceApp: this.sourceApp, ... })`. Or maybe just `new Template(this)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ah thank you very much new Template({ sourceApp: this.sourceApp, ... }) worked.

Answer (score 0):

What I needed is:

new Template({ sourceApp: this.sourceApp, ... })

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).